QGIS 3.34 Calculate area in curved geometries
I want to calculate the cartesian area of a curved geometry, a circle, with a radius of 2500 m.
First, I buffered a point with 2500 m radius and used the function "Convert to curved geometries".
However, I am only able to calculate the area of the resluting circle via: "$area" considering the ellipsoid returning: 19649555 m².
Calculating the cartesian area via the function "area ($geometry)" returns 0 m².
My coordinate system is EPSG:25832 and I am using QGIS 3.34.
